# Need help to submit funcaptcha token into outlook

Tags: node.js, outlook, puppeteer, 2captcha

I'm trying to bypass Funcaptcha outlook using 2captcha, I've tried several ways but nothing worked. This is one ways I use

````js
  const token = await solver.funCaptcha(siteKey, url)

    .then(res => {

      return res.data

    })

    .catch(console.error)

  console.log(token)

  const frame = page.frames()[0]; // Switch to the first frame

  await frame.evaluate("postMessage(JSON.stringify({eventId:'challenge-complete',payload:{sessionToken:'" + token + "'}}),'*')");```

  Maybe someone can help me, I've been looking for a way for days but can't find a solution
````